# What happen's to a closure's delegate when it gets cloned?

Tags: groovy, closures

When a delegate gets changed in a closure, in Groovy, what happens when that closure is cloned?

Does the delegate setting survive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the delegate setting survive?

If by "survive" you mean that the clone will have the same delegate then the answer is "yes".

```
groovy:000> c = {
groovy:001>     append 'Hello'
groovy:002> }
===> groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@31e033f0
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> c.delegate = new StringBuffer()
===> 
groovy:000> d = c.clone()
===> groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@7970c11a
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> c.delegate
===> 
groovy:000> d.delegate
===> 
groovy:000> c()
===> Hello
groovy:000> c.delegate
===> Hello
groovy:000> d.delegate
===> Hello
groovy:000> d.delegate.append 'Goodbye'
===> HelloGoodbye
groovy:000> c.delegate
===> HelloGoodbye
groovy:000> d.delegate
===> HelloGoodbye
groovy:000>
```

Depending on the circumstances, the normal thing to do if you write a method which accepts a closure and your method is going to modify state of the closure (like modifying the delegate or the resolveStrategy) then the correct thing to do is usually to clone the closure and then only mutate those properties on the clone, leaving the original one in tact as it was when it was passed.